# Why doesn't my DO-WHILE loop execute what I imagined it to?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program that will take an input for a limiting value, then output the fibonacci sequence until the limit is reached. This is what I've got so far:

```
        int n1 = 0, n2 = 1, n3 = 0, i, ToInfinity = 3, limit, terms = 0;
        List<int> fibonaccisequence = new List<int>();

        Console.Write("Enter the limiting value: ");
        limit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        fibonaccisequence.Add(n1);
        fibonaccisequence.Add(n2);

        do
        {
            for (i = 2; i < ToInfinity; i++)
            {
                n3 = n1 + n2;
                fibonaccisequence.Add(n3);
                n1 = n2;
                n2 = n3;
                ToInfinity += 1;
                terms += 1;
            }
        }
        while (n3 <= limit);

        Console.WriteLine(fibonaccisequence);
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} terms up to {1].", terms, limit);
```

But whenever I execute the code, it says "Array dimensions exceeded supported range", which obviously means that it is going on forever, instead of stopping at the limit. I may not be seeing something obvious, but can anyone suggest why this isn't working.

Comment: That end condition of that while loop only gets triggered when your for loop is finished

Answer (score 3):

**Let's first see what is happening in your code**

```
for (i = 2; i < ToInfinity; i++)
{
...
}
```

You're running the loop as long as value of `i` is less than `ToInfinity`.
And you're increasing the value of `i` and `ToInfinity` in every iteration by `1`.
So basically this loop is never stopping.

**Let's see how we can reach to your objective**

You're trying to find Fibonacci sequence until the limit is reached.

So I would suggest you to try it using `while` loop first (assuming you're new to this).

**Let's see how you can do it using while loop.**

```
while(n1 + n2 <= limit) // as n3 = will be n1 + n2
{
    n3 = n1 + n2;
    fibonaccisequence.Add(n3);
    n1 = n2;
    n2 = n3;
    
    terms += 1;
}
```

**Note:** You need to initialize the variable "`terms`" with `2`. Cause you've already taken `2` sequences (`n1`, `n2`).

Now I would suggest you to learn little bit more about `do while` loop first. Then try to use that for implementing above logic.

Few resources to learn more about loop

- [C# Loop](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_while_loop.php)
- [C# while and do...while loop](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/do-while-loop)
- [C# - Do...While Loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_do_while_loop.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I guess both ToInfinity and i variables are increasing with same amount so basically for loop will never stop.